# Regex to get Image URL

Tags: java, regex

I want to get url of image from a Java String :

```
String data = "[SyndContentImpl.value=<p><img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-134291"
               title="Design Store(y): Poketo Photo" 
               src="http://3.design-milk.com/images/2013/03/storey-poketo-storefront-1.jpg" 
               alt="Design Store(y): Poketo in style fashion home 
               furnishings featured  Category" width="500" height="333" /></p>";
```

I have tried

```
String pattern = "(http://)+[\\d\\w[-./]]*(.jpg)+";
```

But unable to get url of image from data. 
I finally need this URL

`http://3.design-milk.com/images/2013/03/storey-poketo-storefront-1.jpg`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
imageLinkPattern = linkPattern | imagePostfix
```

so we have:

```
String pattern = "(http(s?):/)(/[^/]+)+" + "\.(?:jpg|gif|png)";
```

this pattern accepts image of type jpg|gif|png only

Comment: "(http(s?):)|([/|.|\\w|\\s])*." + "(?:jpg|gif|png)" Its giving only 1.jpg.

Comment: had to remove | after http to make  it fully working. thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 2):

```
String regex = "http(s?)://([\\w-]+\\.)+[\\w-]+(/[\\w- ./]*)+\\.(?:[gG][iI][fF]|[jJ][pP][gG]|[jJ][pP][eE][gG]|[pP][nN][gG]|[bB][mM][pP])";

Matcher m = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(data);

if (m.find())
  System.out.println(m.group(0));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are parsing html,you should use an [html parser](http://jtidy.sourceforge.net/)

---

If it's not html,you can use this regex

```
http://[^"]+?\\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png)
```

`[^"]` matches any character except `"`

`[^"]+` matches 1 to many `"`

Comment: After escaping i used this  "http://[^\"]+?\\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png)"  But its not returning url.